# In FLUTTER / DART, why do we sometimes add a question mark to "String" when declaring a variable?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, types

In the demo app, we find an instance of **"final String? title;"**  - > Why do we add this "?" after the type String ?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  **final String? title;**

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}
```

**In the same way, why when using it, we add a "!" ?**

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: **Text(widget.title!),**
      ),
      body: Center(
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`variable_type ? name_of_variable;` means that **name_of_variable** can be null.

`variable_type  name_of_variable1;`  means that **name_of_variable1** cannot be null and you should initialize it immediately.

`late variable_type  name_of_variable2;`  means that **name_of_variable2** cannot be null and you can initialize it later.

```
late variable_type name_of_variable3;
variable_type ? name_of_variable4;
name_of_variable4=some_data;
name_of_variable3=name_of_variable4!;// name_of_variable4! means that you are sure 100% it never will be null
```

Real example with int type:

```
int ? a=null; // OK
int  b=null; // b cannot be equal null
late int c =null; // c cannot be equal null
late int d;
d=5; //OK

late int d; // if you never initialize it, you'll get exception

int e=5;
int? f=4;
int ? z;
e=f!; // OK, You are sure that f never is null

e=z!;// You get exception because z is equal null
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation ! It helps a lot.

Comment: What does "late" mean in your examples ?

Comment: ```late``` means that reference cannot be equal to null but you can assign to some value it later
Be sure, you should have been initialised before accessing it

Answer (score 15):

This is with null safety, the question mark means that this `String?` can possibly be null and flutter will allow you to assign null to it. `String` can never be null and you'll get an error before compiling.

If you define a variable `String? name`, and you want to use it later in a Text widget, you'll get an error. Because Text widgets only accept non-nullable types. But if you are sure that `name` will never be null, you tell flutter to not worry about it and that you know what you are doing, you do this by adding the `!`  like this : `Text(name!)`.

Comment: I was wondering if it had something to do with null safety. Thank you so much for your quick answer. What about the "!" in "TEXT(WIDGET.TITLE!) ?

Comment: I edited my answer, and believe that I answered your second question regarding the `!`.

Comment: It has everything to do with null safety, it is writing dart in null-safety. You should check it out and read into, it'll make your code faster, smaller and less prone to bugs.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Very clear! As you might have guessed, I'm a beginner with flutter development. But loving it ! :)

Comment: Was wondering if "virtual teams" of developers can be created in Stack Overflow, so that beginners like me can share with more "advanced" developers ?

Comment: Keep learning and investing in yourself, ask well written questions and you'll get better answers. You get better with time with and practice, everybody is learning everyday. You're most welcome!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230514/discussion-between-sylvainjack-and-huthaifa-muayyad).

Answer (score 0):

I believe adding a `?` is a null safety feature introduced in the recent time flutter update. It basically means the value can be null and it won't throw any error

Answer (score 0):

```
variable_type ? name_of_variable; means that name_of_variable can be null.
```

`variable_type  name_of_variable1;` means that `name_of_variable1` cannot be null and you should initialize it immediately.